# How to execute a filter on Controller-level before the Controller's OnActionExecuting-method

Tags: asp.net-core

I created a filter **MyFilterAttribute** for my ASP.NET Core application.
As you can see in the code example below, I'm using it on a controller, so that the filter is executed before all actions are executed.

In addition, the controller has also an own OnActionExecuting() method.

My problem is that the OnActionExecuting() of the controller is executed before **MyFilterAttribute** is executed, while I need **MyFilterAttribute** to be executed before the OnActionExecuting() in the controller. Is there any way to obtain this behavior? I already tried to assign a negative Order-value to **MyFilterAttribute** (since it inherits from ActionFilterAttribute whic implements IOrderedFilter), but it didn't help.

```
public class MyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionExecutingContext)
    {
        //do some checks
    }
}


[MyFilter]
public class MyController()
{
    [NonAction]
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if(currentUrl != urlThatDoesNotNeedChecks)
        {
            //do some checks
        }            
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //read some data and return the view
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you want to override `OnActionExecuting` method of the controller and not to create another additional filter? More than one filter could be assigned. And you could assign filter directly on the action, so URL check will be unneeded.

Comment: @Set because in the OnActionExecuting of the controller I'm also retrieving some data from the database that I'll need in the various actions. This way I can avoid to retrieve it twice from the database.

Answer (score -1):

It all has to do with the order the different filters are executed in relation to the controller. In ASP.NET Core, you have several different filters to choose from, executed in this order:

- Authorization Filter
- Resource Filter
- Action Filter

If you change your filter to implement `IResourceFilter`, instead of `IActionFilter`, then it'll be executed before the controller's `OnActionExecuting` function.

You can read more about it at [Filters in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1)